# progressbar IsIndeterminate not working while other heavy task running

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar

I use the following code to update my progressBar when using min and max values while
doing some heavy tasks and it works fine. I have a few tasks that can not provide
a update status by increment value, so I wanted to use IsIndeterminate so it shows
something is going on. When I set it to IsIndeterminate it freezes while the heavy task is running. What is the best way to get a progressbar to run in IsIndeterminate. I tried using a DispatchTimer, but the tick was never called while the heavy task was running. I'm curious what the best way to handle this would be. Thanks for any help.

```
public static class extensionRefresh {
    private static Action EmptyDelegate = delegate() { };
    public static void Refresh(this UIElement uiElement) {
    uiElement.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, EmptyDelegate);
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you simply use a background worker ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds to me like you are blocking the UI thread, and that's why the progress bar gets stuck.

Use BackgroundWorker if you want to do a long task, so that way it uses a worker thread and the progress bar would work